# Statement must be prepended with case label : SWITCH method in onClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio, switch-statement

Here I do not want to use old pattern of Switch eg `case R.id.btnCoolNames:` in `switch`.
I want to use `if` statement in `switch`. I using this `switch` inside `onClick` method to call `cardView`.

So I face this error/pop-up when I write this code.
Maybe my code is not right because I do not find any example of this.

How can I fix this??

[image: Warning: Statement must be prepended with case label]

Comment: "I want to use if statement in switch" - what makes you think that's valid syntax? It looks like you just need to get rid of the switch part entirely... what you've got is valid if you remove `switch (v.getId()) {` and the closing brace.

Comment: Why use a switch if you are just doing if/else's? Can you share where you saw this "new" style switch that uses if's?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks now I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right but you do little mistake.
**If you using `if` then do not use `switch`.**

Remove `switch(v.getId())`

Your Final Code will be:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            int vId = v.getId();

            if (vId == R.id.chatcodeBtn1){
                //your code
            }
            else if(vId == R.id.chatcodeBtn2){
                //your code
            }
            else if (vId == R.id.chatcodeBtn3){
                // your code
            }

    }
```

**Happy Coding :)**